# Objeto Json no ionic 2

Tags: node.js, ionic2, express.js, angular

Estou começando com Ionic 2 e Node.js e estou tentando consumir a API que criei, mas estou tendo dificuldades em localizar o problema quando tento gerar uma listagem com ngFor a partir de um JSON, pelo que já li o ngFor precisa de um Objeto JSON para funcionar, então criei o provider para obter esse objeto.

```
@Injectable()
export class ProdutoService {

  rest: any;

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello ProdutoService Provider');
  }

  load() {
    if (this.rest) {
      return Promise.resolve(this.rest);
    }
    // Dont have the data yet
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/produtos/')
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.rest = data.results;
          resolve(this.rest);
        });
    });
  }
}
```

produto.ts

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-produtos',
  templateUrl: 'produtos.html',
  providers: [ProdutoService]
})

export class ProdutosPage {

  public produtos: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public produtoService: ProdutoService){
    this.loadProduto();
  }

  loadProduto(){
    this.produtoService.load()
    .then(rest => {
      this.produtos = rest;
    });
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ProdutosPage');
  }
}
```

e minha página:

```html
 produto.html  
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of produtos">
      <ion-avatar item-left>
        <img src="{{item.foto}}">
      </ion-avatar>
      <h2>{{item.produto}} {{item.categoria}}</h2>
      <p>{{item.gender}}</p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

e funciona perfeitamente se usar o `randomuser.me/api`, mas quando uso a minha API não dá nenhum erro, simplesmente não carrega nada, veja os dois JSON, para mim "leigo" são iguais, mas;

randon:

```
{"results":[{"gender":"male","name":{"title":"mr","first":"hunter","last":"smith"},"location":{"street":"6823 peel st","city":"stirling","state":"northwest ....
```

minha:

```
[{"id":100,"produto":"Arroz Parbolizado Tio Joao 5kg Tp1","descricao":"","categoria":18,"foto":"r6ccgtwize8o8g44gg.jpg","ean":"","status":"Ativo"}]
```

já fiz o retorno com `{"resuls":{"id":100,"produto":"Arroz Parbolizado Tio Joao 5kg` ... e nada.

Aproveito e coloco parte do API que retorna o JSON;
model:

```
var db=require('../dbconnection'); //reference of dbconnection.js

var Produtos={

    getAllProdutos:function(callback){

        return db.query("Select * from produtos",callback);

    },
};

module.exports=Produtos;
```

rota:

```
Produtos.getAllProdutos(function(err,rows){
if(err)
  {
    res.json(err);
  }
  else
  {
    res.json(rows);
  }
});
```

Já tentei varias maneiras e não achei nenhum modo que funcionasse.

Comment: O seu service está retornando o objeto RESULTS (this.rest = data.results;), porém seu objeto não o possui. (note ainda que na sua tentativa de mudar o retorno, vc escreveu errado -> {"resuls":{... Tente mudar o seu service para retornar `this.rest = data;`

Comment: obrigado, nas várias tentativas de retorna acabei não vendo. seria melhor mudar a api, tem alguma indicação de tutorial ? pois todas com mysql que vi são bem básicas.

Comment: Nesta linha this.rest = data.results; vc está pegando a chave results, então seu retorno json tem que ter {"results":[{"alguma coisa"}, {"outra coisa"}], se quiser pegar apenas [{"alguma coisa"}, {"outra coisa"}] muda a linha para this.rest = data;